# TwoWayGridView onItemSelected not working when the TwoWayGridView get the Focus first

Tags: android

I develop a TV project,I use the TwoWayGridView in the Horizontal page,but i find that.
mTwoWayGridView .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
TwoWayGridView onItemSelected  not working when the  TwoWayGridView get the Focus first.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(TwoWayAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "position:" + position); //not print when the foces first

}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: just when I move　to then TwoWayGridView With handle For the first time ,onItemSelected　not Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the adapter views are not calling the onItemSelected method the first time because the first item in the adapter is already selected so is not triggering the method until it changes.

I solved it setting a OnFocusChangeListener on the adapter view and managing my self when the view has the focus and the first item is selected.

I hope this helps.